# How to install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation, ssms

I have [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=58CE885D-508B-45C8-9FD3-118EDD8E6FFF&displaylang=en) already installed, and now I want to install [SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en).

I've tried with the only two options that look feasible:

- [...] Add features to an existing installation
- Launch a wizard to change your edition of SQL Server 2008 [...]

But in the Features Selection step, Management Studio never appears as an option.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't looked further into this but can confirm this is what happens - perhaps due to the service pack levels differing? (installed instance being SP1 and the tool installer not)

I just used control panel and changed the installed SQL 2008 to remove the database service instance.

Then I installed [the MSSQL 2008 Express edition that includes the standard tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7522A683-4CB2-454E-B908-E805E9BD4E28&displaylang=en) - and the option for management studio was there to check... not an elegant solution but it worked - so I didn't bother to figure out the original problem.

Comment: Looks like that's the only way to go. I didn't wanted to download it all over again... How comes MS doesn't have such awesome tools as Aptitude in Linux...

Comment: Oh no, are we trying to insite a relious war again?

Answer (score 1):

Check this blogpost:

http://blogs.msdn.com/billramo/archive/2009/02/20/sql-server-2008-management-studio-express-released-to-the-web.aspx